# in operator not working on a large list

Tags: list, python-3.x, in-operator

I'm using python 3.5.1 both on windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I have a list that contains more than one million string items in it. Items are unicode strings of Turkish words.
I check the existence of some strings in that list using the in operator. Most of the answers are correct.
However some strings return False, even they exist in the list.
I tried the same cehecks after converting the list to a set.
But nothing changed.
What can I do to obtain correct results.
Thanks.

I am using utf-8 encodings everywhere.

[Related codes are here](https://github.com/ahmetax/trderlem/blob/master/kokKelimeler.py)

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: Are you comparing strings with different encodings?

Comment: My codes are at: https://github.com/ahmetax/trderlem/blob/master/kokKelimeler.py

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. But, it was not a list problem.
In order to prepare the list, I was reading the related file line by line, stripping it and appending to the list. In that process some of the items are lost. I don't know the reason yet.
But the following lines create the exact list without any loss:

> with open("./veri/dertop.txt",encoding="utf-8") as fin:
>       dertop = fin.read().splitlines()